# Dynamic Rendering of Div based on Apex Controller Value

Tags: apex, visualforce, rerender, actionfunction

I would like to reRender a Div based on some logic. Initially the div will be set as display:none as per the logic (Checking whether the variable is null or not).

But after passing value to controller through apex:actionFunction, I am setting up the variable with proper value. During this time, I am expecting the previous div will be set as display:block. But unfortunately it is not happening.

Here is the code -
Apex:actionFunction:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="verifyJavaScript" action="{!verify}" rerender="displayPreference"/>
```

Div:

```
<div class="row" style="{!IF(selectedPreference != null, 'display:block', 'display:none')}" id="displayPreference">
    <div class="col-lg-12 form-group form-group-lg">

        &nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="promoOptIn" rendered="{!IF(selectedPreference != null , true , false)}" name="promoOptIn" type="checkbox" value="1" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Register for Promo Opt In?
        <apex:inputhidden id="promoOptIns" value="{!promoOptIns}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public PageReference verify(){
    PageReference ProductRefresh = ApexPages.currentPage();
    //Setting up the variable selectedPreference here based on logic
    return ProductRefresh;
}
```

Could you please help me to understand what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `<div>` use `<apex:outputPanel>` and it will render as `div` in HTML.

```
<apex:outputPanel class="row" style="{!IF(selectedPreference != null, 'display:block', 'display:none')}" id="displayPreference">
    <div class="col-lg-12 form-group form-group-lg">

        &nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="promoOptIn" rendered="{!(selectedPreference != null)}" name="promoOptIn" type="checkbox" value="1" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Register for Promo Opt In?
        <apex:inputhidden id="promoOptIns" value="{!promoOptIns}" />
    </div>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Otherwise, wrap entire `<div>` block inside an `<apex:outputPanel>` and rerender that outputPanel as follows:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="displayPreference">
<div class="row" style="{!IF(selectedPreference != null, 'display:block', 'display:none')}">
    <div class="col-lg-12 form-group form-group-lg">

        &nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="promoOptIn" rendered="{!selectedPreference != null}" name="promoOptIn" type="checkbox" value="1" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Register for Promo Opt In?
        <apex:inputhidden id="promoOptIns" value="{!promoOptIns}" />
    </div>
</div>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Side note: don't use `if(,true,false)` in rendered condition, use `rendered="{!selectedPreference != null}"` as it displays only at `true` condition.

Refer [apex:outputPanel](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputPanel.htm?search_text=outputPanel)

> A set of content that is grouped together, rendered with an HTML  tag, `<div>` tag, or neither. Use an `<apex:outputPanel>` to group components together for AJAX refreshes.
>
> This component supports HTML pass-through attributes using the "html-" prefix. Pass-through attributes are attached to the generated container tag, `<div>` or `<span>`, depending on the value of the layout attribute.

Comment: Thanks Santanu. I made the changes suggested by you, but still the outputPanel is not getting reRendered.

Comment: did you try both the options? Also, are you assigning `selectedPreference` variable value properly?

Comment: Yes. Both the options

Comment: Also, are you assigning selectedPreference variable value properly in controller method?

Comment: Here is the code - public PageReference verify(){
        
        List<Contact> allContacts = <Query Contact>;
        if(allContacts.size() == 1){
            List<Preferences__c> allPreferences = <Query Preference>;
            if(allPreferences.size() == 1){
                selectedPreference = allPreferences.get(0);
            }
        }

        return ProductRefresh;
    }

Comment: you can print `selectedPreference` at visualforce to check if that value is properly assigned after rerendering